# Using the word "native" in non-restrictive appositives

Tags: grammaticality, appositives

Which way is grammatically correct, using it as an adjective ("native") or as a noun ("a native" or "the native")?

> Alice Shimmer, **native** of Shiksenburg, was less forthcoming about
>   the unconstitutional coup in Ukraine of February 2014.

or

> Alice Shimmer, **a native** of Shiksenburg, was less forthcoming about
>   the unconstitutional coup in Ukraine of February 2014.

or

> Alice Shimmer, **the native** of Shiksenburg, was less forthcoming about
>   the unconstitutional coup in Ukraine of February 2014.

?

I think I've heard all of these three so I don't know which one is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either—with the caveat that if you drop the article, you should use the preposition **to**.

So:

> Alice Shimmer, native ***to*** Shiksenburg, was less forthcoming about the unconstitutional coup in Ukraine of February 2014.

Or:

> Alice Shimmer, **a** native of Shiksenburg, was less forthcoming about the unconstitutional coup in Ukraine of February 2014.

Note that although both are grammatical, the second is probably more idiomatic.

---

You would not use **the** unless Alice Shimmer were the ***only*** native of Shiksenburg.

However, this version is acceptable:

> Alice Shimmer, ***one of the natives*** of Shiksenburg, was less forthcoming about the unconstitutional coup in Ukraine of February 2014.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any explanation as to why, if without an article, the "of" must be changed to "to"?

Comment: @brilliant Here, *native to* is used as an adjective (and doesn't take an article because it isn't countable) while *native of* is used as a (countable) noun. The reason *native to* would be less common is because it's more often used to refer to animals or plants than people. (*This animal is native to that region.*)